# Elasticsearch 1.6 insert 19-digits number into Long field - the last 3 digits rounded

Tags: java, api, elasticsearch

I inserted data into Elasticsearch by Java API (JDK 1.8). In java input data is  long data type with value 7153256312100466443. In Elasticsearch output is [7153256312100467000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bmbxm.png)

However, I query by curl the output is [7153256312100466443](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo0ra.png)

Answer (score 1):

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_inaccurate1)
describes similar limitation in js:

> Precision Integers (numbers without a period or exponent notation) are
>   considered accurate up to 15 digits

looks like Chrome developers respect it.

[image: raw response]
[image: parsed response]

Comment: how to input a JSON object and response like you test. I'm interesting that.